# translate Last Modified Date of a file from UNIX to local timezone

Tags: php, datetime, unix

Using PHP, I am trying to retrieve the Last Modified Date of files, exactly as they appear in Windows Explorer.  The PHP code looks like this: `date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', filemtime($file));`.  Here is an example of a file in Windows Explorer and the corresponding output from the PHP script:
[image]

Clearly, the Last Modified Date from the PHP script does not match the date being displayed in Windows Explorer.  The subject file was created in the Central Standard Timezone where daylight savings time is practiced.  Is there a way to convert the UNIX date returned by PHP's filemtime() to the local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method you need here is probably `date_default_timezone_set`. There's [a list of all the timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) that are supported by PHP, but the one you'll need for central time is `America/Chicago`.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    $fileDate = date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', filemtime($file));
?>
```

[Here's the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) on the timezone set method.

Comment: Presto!  That fixed the problem.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it, happy coding!